# Теорема Пифагора в C#

Tags: c#

Привет народ. Слушайте, помогите, перевести теорему Пифагора (a2 + b2 = c2). [Вот что у меня есть](http://i078.radikal.ru/1112/fc/394aa42460fa.png).

Как сделать так, чтобы в `label3` получилось то, что в формуле или вообще, как реализовать это?

**UPD**: Вопрос, почему в превью картинка видна, а в сообщение нет?

Comment: почитай лучше сам как работать с GUI, как передавать сообщения и обрабатывать действия, а то видно, что ты просто накидал редактором вьюх и кнопок и ждешь чуда =) 

ЗЫ label3.setText("result " + c2);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

textBox1 будет А

textBox2 будет В

label3 - это результат

```
label3.Text = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text),2) + 
                        Math.Pow(Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text),2)).ToString();
```

только не называйте так текстбоксы, лейблы и любые другие элементы интерфейса!

и на кнопочке "Почитать" выглядит хуже, чем "ПоСчитать"=)

Comment: Упс... ошибка, спасибо :)...

только не называйте так текстбоксы, лейблы и любые другие элементы интерфейса!

Что вы имели ввиду?

Comment: переменные нужно называть так, чтобы посторонние люди тоже могли понять, что они означают, набор автоматически сгенерированых названий элементов интерфейса - ``textBox1, label2, button3`` - ужаснейшая практика! в вашем случае ``textBox1 - FirstLeg`` - будет буквально означать "первый катет"(если верить [википедии](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathetus)), ко всему остальному тоже желательно использовать более интуитивно понятные названия

Comment: Оу... я так уже 3,5 месяца... А что не так в таких названиях, если программы делаются не для других(исходный код), а для себя...

Comment: однажды Стив Макконнелл сказал:``"Пишите код так, как будто сопровождать его будет склонный к насилию психопат, который знает, где вы живете"``

это относится к любой написаной вами строчке кода, просто примите это за аксиому и следуйте ей, хуже от этого никому не будет

Comment: Ага, Вам же потом будет легче вносить изменения в свой же код, когда потребуется.